# Can't synthesise NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nswindow

I'm trying to synthesise my NSWindow "loginscreen" but I keep getting the error "property implementation must have its declaration in interface "appdelegate"

This is the part of the header

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
@private
NSWindow *window;
NSWindow *loginscreen;
```

And this my method:

```
@synthesize loginscreen = _loginscreen;
```

Any suggestions? thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ARC you need to add the following line to your AppDelegate.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSWindow *loginWindow;
```

If you are not using ARC you should instead use:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSWindow *loginWindow;
```

This line would go after the {} block in `@interface` but before the `@end`.

Comment: If you are creating the window with Interface Builder you will also have to bind the instance created in IB to the variable you have synthesized. You do this by adding `IBOutlet` to the `@property` statement before `NSWindow`. Then in Interface Builder Control drag from the "File's Owner" to the window you want that variable to represent.

Comment: @haseo98 If answers work for you, you should accept them with the big check mark. It helps others know what are valid answers.